# Finding polynomial in modular? // $(n!)+1$ prime

Tags: number-theory

> **Questions:**
>
> 3. Find a polynomial $f(x)$ satisfying $$f(x) \equiv x^2 + 3x + 4 \pmod {13}$$ $$f(x) \equiv 7x + 1 \pmod {17}$$
> 4. Is $(14!)^2+1$ prime or not? Give your full reasoning.

Well I have never seen this kind of problem studying elementary number theory. and I don't know how to solve them. What is that third question asking for? I have seen number and using CRT, I could solve some kinds of problem.
But this time, it is polynomial.

Comment: Use Sun-Ze's theorem (also known as "Chinese Remainder Theorem") applied to each of the coefficients individually.

Comment: Hint: $29$ divides $(14!)^2 +1$.

Comment: @Santiago,can you explain your hint a little more, wolfram alpha also give this hint :)

Comment: @studentforever http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16206

Comment: Thanks, @barto. I actually added the answer here. I just wonder how the above hint would be hint.

Answer (score 1):

Find numbers $a,b,c$ such that $$a \equiv 1\mod 13\text{ and } a \equiv 0 \mod 17  $$ and $$b \equiv 3 \mod 13 \text{ and } b \equiv 7 \mod 17$$and $$c \equiv 4 \mod 13 \text{ and } c \equiv 1 \mod 17$$ with CRT and the polynomial can be $$ax^2+bx+c$$ and you can also add $$dx^n$$ such that $13\cdot17\mid d.$

---

For second question: $$14!\times 14! \equiv 1\cdot2\cdot3 \cdots 14 \times (29-14) \cdot (29-13) \cdots (29-1) \equiv 28! \equiv -1 \mod 29$$ and so $$29 \mid (14!^2+1).$$

Comment: Second is Amazing.. wow... i m so impressed .and i dont know well about first question

Comment: Coefficient-wise Chinese Remainder  Theorem. Not a big thing.

Comment: Oh i understood it haha thanks